# Output heading only once in channel entry

Tags: tags, entry

I am trying to output the heading "Related Articles" only once before all the blog submissions.  The way I have it coded below, it's outputting heading in every entry.  I've put it in multiple places and no luck.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
        <div id="main">
            <section class="section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                            {!-- IF PREMIUM PAGE > ONLINE EXERCISES --}
                            {if last_segment == 'online-exercises'}{!--***--}
                                <ul id="online-exercises-list">
                                    {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="200" orderby="title" sort="asc" }

                                        {if no_results}
                                            {exp:channel:categories}
                                                {if last_segment ==  category_url_title}
                                                <h1>{blog_content}</h1>
                                                {/if}
                                            {/exp:channel:categories}
                                            <h2>No Items in this category</h2>
                                            <h3>Sorry, but here are no listings under this category at this time.</h3>
                                        {/if}

                                        <li><a href="/blog/article/{url_title}" title="{title}">{title}</a></li>

                                    {/exp:channel:entries}
                                </ul>

                            {!-- OTHERWISE, SHOW STANDARD CATEGORY ENTRIES --}
                            {if:else}

                                {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="7" paginate="bottom" }

                                    {if category_description == "y"}
                                        <article class="description-block">
                                            <div class="text-block">
                                                <div class="text-holder">
                                                   {blog_content}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </article>
                                    {if:else}


                                        {if no_results}
                                            {exp:channel:categories}
                                                {if last_segment ==  category_url_title}
                                                <h1>{category_name}</h1>
                                                {/if}
                                            {/exp:channel:categories}
                                            <h2>No Items in this category</h2>
                                            <h3>Sorry, but here are no listings under this category at this time.</h3>
                                        {/if}

<div class="row">
    <h1 class="style">Related Articles</span></h1>
</div>  

                                        <article class="post-block">
                                            <h2><a href="/blog/article/{url_title}">{title}</a></h2>
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <span class="author">by {author}</span>
                                                <span class="date">{entry_date format=" %F %d, %Y"}</span><br />
                                                {!--<span>in {categories}<a href="/blog/category/{category_url_title}/">{category_name},</a> {/categories}
                                                </span>--}
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="text-block">
                                                {if "{blog-videos:total_rows search:blog-videos_active='=y'}" > '0'}
                                                    {blog-videos search:blog-videos_active='=y' limit="1"}
                                                        <div class="placeholder alignleft">
                                                        {if blog-videoupload != ""}
                                                            <a href='/blog/article/{url_title}'>
                                                                {if blog-videos_thumb != ''}
                                                                    {exp:ce_img:single src="{blog-videos_thumb}" max_height="120" max_width="200" crop="yes" cache_dir="/cache" alt="{blog-images_title}"}
                                                                {if:else}
                                                                    <img src="/themes/site_themes/site/graphics/playvid.png" height='120' width='200' alt="playvid" />
                                                                {/if}
                                                            </a>
                                                        {if:else}
                                                            {exp:antenna url='{blog-videos_url}' max_width="570" cache_minutes="120" wmode="transparent|opaque|window"}
                                                                <a href="/blog/article/{url_title}"><img src="{video_thumbnail}" height="120" width="200" alt="{video_title}" /></a>
                                                            {/exp:antenna}
                                                        {/if}
                                                        </div>
                                                    {/blog-videos}
                                                {if:else}
                                                    {blog-images search:blog-images_active='=y' limit="1"}
                                                        <div class="placeholder alignleft">
                                                            {if '{blog-images_file}' != ''}
                                                                <a href="/blog/article/{url_title}">{exp:ce_img:single src="{blog-images_file}" height="200" width="200" crop="yes" cache_dir="" alt="{blog-images_title}"}</a>
                                                            {if:else}
                                                                <a class="float-right" href="/blog/article/{url_title}">{exp:ce_img:single src="{blog-images_after}" height="100" width="50" crop="yes" cache_dir="/cache" alt="{blog-images_title}"}</a>
                                                                <a class="float-right" href="/blog/article/{url_title}">{exp:ce_img:single src="{blog-images_before}" height="100" width="50" crop="yes" cache_dir="/cache" alt="{blog-images_title}"}</a>
                                                            {/if}
                                                        </div>
                                                    {/blog-images}
                                                {/if}
                                                <div class="text-holder">
                                                    {exp:eehive_hacksaw allow="" chars="275"  }
                                                        <p>{blog_content}</p>
                                                    {/exp:eehive_hacksaw}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </article>
                                        <div class="read-more"><a href="/blog/article/{url_title}">READ MORE<img src="{site_url}themes/site_themes/site/images/more-arrow.png" alt="more arrow" /></a></div>
                                        <hr style="clear:both; width: 100%;"/>
                                    {/if}

                                {/exp:channel:entries}

                            {/if}

                        </section>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional statement to only output the heading on the first row:

```
{if count == "1"}
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="style">Related Articles</span></h1>
</div>  
{/if}
```

Comment: I already tried that too and nothing shows up at all using  `{if count == "1"}`

Comment: It will, you just need to declutter your template and find the error - you have _a lot_ going on. Strip it down to just a single `channel:entries` tag and you'll find it works, then slowly add back everything else.

Comment: You don't even need quotes around the `1`. `{if count == 1}` works fine.